# how to append multiple columns of a huge dataset in a csv file to a data frame

Tags: python

I have a dataset in a csv file and I need to append some of its columns to a list. the dataset is very huge and its length is 2222678 rows.Here is my code to append its columns to list. However it gets stuck and my computer runs slowly. I appreciate if anyone can tell me is there a way to append that huge data into a data frame faster?

```
 dataset = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/ha/GTruth/sumo-output-w/file_name.csv')

 line=0
 for line in range(len(dataset)):
    input_data.append(dataset.loc[line,["pos_x","pos_y"]])
    output_data.append(dataset.loc[line,["labels"]])
```

Comment: `apply()` function runs much faster than traditional for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are appending your column data line by line, hence the large amount of time. I would suggest transforming those columns into lists like so:

```
input_data_x = list(dataset["pos_x"])
input_data_y = list(dataset["pos_y"])
```

If you want tuples of x and y you can do it like this (time consuming):

```
input_data = [(x, y) for x,y in zip(input_data_x, input_data_y)]
```

For the output data:

```
output_data = list(dataset["labels"])
```

Additionally, I do not know what this data will be used for, but **numpy arrays** operations are inherently faster than **lists**, so I would suggest using **numpy arrays**.

**EDIT**

Since you are using this data for `kmeans` and you need to structure it properly then I suggest using `numpy arrays` which makes things easier:

```
input_data = dataset[["x", "y"]].to_numpy()  # 2d-array with shape (n samples, n features)
output_data = dataset["labels"].to_numpy()
```

This way your data is already in the correct format, ready to be used by the `kmeans` model.

Comment: I want to apply kmeans clustering on them

Comment: Okay, then you I would suggest numpy arrays instead of lists. I made an edit to the answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list from a pandas column (or Series) pretty easily.

```
labels = list(dataset.labels)
pos_x = list(dataset.pos_x)
pos_y = list(dataset.pos_y)

input_data.extend(labels)
output_data.extend(pos_x)
output_data.extend(pos_x)
```